# Broke one of the two power steering pump brackets/anchors

Tags: power-steering, motor-mounts, screw

Vehicle:  Toyota Tacoma 2007 V6 4L

While I was taking my power steering pump out, I manager to brake one of the two brackets (or anchors) that attach it to the main body of the engine.  It is an SOL type of situation, i.e. not repairable unless the whole engine is taken out and the thing us welded back onto it but I don't think even that is possible because it would have to be calibrated to match the hole positions on the pump, which is a c**pchute at best.

I think the thing could be mounted in just one anchor, especially because the one that is left has the longer screw.  But if that screw became loose, the pump might wiggle and I was wondering if that may be an issue and cause the fluid hose to come off.  Especially because that will compromise the position of the pulley relative to the serpentine belt.

So I am reaching out to the guru community to assess the severity of this breakage.  Do you think the pump will be okay remounted on only one anchor?  Is there any way to restore the fixed position of the pump on the serpentine belt?  I still have the broken off piece, in case it can somehow be used to remedy the situation.

Answer (score 2):

While one bolt *might* be able to hold the pump in place, it won't keep it firm. What this will give you is just enough movement, the serpentine belt will not stay in place. It will pop off, maybe not in the first few seconds, but as soon as you put enough strain on the power steering, it will deflect enough and your belt will be off. The reason there are usually at least two (or more), is because this anchors whatever accessory is being tied in. Less than that and you have the possibility for deflection in one plane of reference, which will give the belt a chance to pop off.

If this is on a bracket, you should probably go to a junk yard and see if you can get a replacement. If this is not possible, you're going to need to see about getting it repaired through welding or what have you. If it's not a bracket, but is attached directly to the engine, maybe you can have a Helicoil put in or something to that effect.

Comment: i cannot replace the bracket, it is one piece from the engine housing, i.e. it would need to be welded on

Comment: And then I didn't read you description very well, sorry about that... I see there was originally only two bolts. I will edit my answer above to reflect. Even so, if this is in the front of the engine, this should actually be a cover, which *can* be replaced. I would look into this. I cannot imagine a company like Toyota making an engine layout where something like this would not be fixable or replaceable, it just would not make sense.